# Blender file view

Tags: python, 3d-view

I am using Blender 2.82a.
From 3D View Port when I save my Blender code, I am able to save as .blender file.
I can see the file I save in 'Blender file view' .
When I try to retrieve, I am able to get 3D View port correctly, BUT what I see at the bottom right corner of Blender file view' is 'Cancel" and 'Open Text'. I am unable to select my blender file to see the actual blender code.
Please advise how to fix this problem - I cant pick TEXT for Blender file

Comment: Hi. I suggest adding some pictures to illustrate your problem. Also, please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: I think you are trying to edit/text (a *.py script file) when you are looking at/viewing through the "3D view" editor (*.blend) for modeling objects.    (One way is to:) Change the editor by selecting the tab labeled "Scripting" along the top/row.   I'm refering to the Tabs to the right of File, Edit, Render, Window,.Help.   You will then see a "Text" Menu selection to open your script.    You will hopefully see your script in the "Recents" window area (bottom left for me).

Comment: I do have a screen shot - BUT how do I add the screen shot and where do I add?  When I save my Blender file, I can see it being saved with extension .blender. BUT when I try to go via the File/Open or Text/Open - in the Blender File View, I can not see the blender file. At the BOTTOM, Right had corner of Blender File View, I see 'Cancel' followed by 'Open Text' Buttons. I want to see my blender code back in 3D View .

Comment: Happy to share screen shot, BUT I do not know where and how to attach in Stack Exchange, Pleaselet me know how to attach.

Comment: Thanks Gentlemen - I got this fixed. By opening Text Editor Window and then the 3D View window in that order solved my problem. Thanks for your replies. I guess this issue os now stands closed.